# Lift 2.6: How to append a NodeSeq rather than using SetHtml()

Tags: lift

I use SetHtml() all the time to swap chunks of HTML as part of the return trip of an ajax call, ie. when my "Edit Item" ajax call returns, I swap the contents of  with form elements representing the "Item" to be edited.

Now I'm trying to add a *new* item to a list (so that "Item 2" appears as the next li under "Item 1").  My html looks like (this is a greatly simplified version) this:

```
<div data-lift="form.ajax">
    <div data-lift="JsCmdTest">
        <test:submitbutton></test:submitbutton>
        <ul id="targetdiv">
            <li>Item 1</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my Lift code looks like this

```
class JsCmdTest extends StatefulSnippet
{
  def dispatch = { case "render" => render }
  def bindStuff(ns: NodeSeq): NodeSeq =
  {
    bind("test", ns,
      "submitbutton" -> SHtml.ajaxButton("Go", ()=> {
          val newLi = Jx(<div>Item 2</div>)
          (ElemById("targetdiv") ~> JsFunc("appendChild", newLi.toJs)).cmd
      })
    )
  }
  def render: (NodeSeq)=>NodeSeq = (ns: NodeSeq) => {
    bindStuff(ns)
  }
}
```

When I run this, the ajax call is fired, and the response looks fine, but I get the following error in the browser console:

```
The server call succeeded, but the returned Javascript contains an error: NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element is null.
```

WANTED: a way to append replacement HTML to an existing < ul >.  I feel like the way I'm going about appending seems way more esoteric than probably needed, but i haven't found any other way to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you're using a *very* old syntax for binding. If I am not mistaken, a new way for bindings was introduced somewhere in lift-2, and it is the recommended one since somewhere in lift-2.2. (I'll write the syntax below.)
- JsFunc is an anonymous function, like `def local(a: A): B`. You don't need to send anonymous function, you can send the code directly. (See below.)
- So, I recommend something like this:

`import net.liftweb.http.js.{JsExp, JsCmd, JsCmds}`

```
import net.liftweb.http.js.jquery.JqJE.{JqAppend, JqId}

def render = {
    val appendJs: JsExp = JqId("targetdiv") ~> JqAppend(newLi)
    "#mySubmitButton" #> SHtml.ajaxButton("Go", () => appendJs.cmd)
}
```

You'll also have to adapt the HTML a little, like using a normal `<button>` with `id="mySubmitButton"`.

Comment: Wow, I had never come across the Jq corner of the js library.  Now that I scrounge around there, I also see JqJsCmds.AppendHtml, which wraps the ~> syntax into a simple call that looks very much like JsCmds.SetHtml.  Awesome.

Comment: Now, a follow-on question (so I continue to learn to fish instead of being handed fish...), I own every Lift book out there (literally), and I don't believe any mentioned the JqJE section of the library.  How did you know this?  Must one read the Lift source code to learn stuff like this (or trip over the info in a stackoverflow post as I usually do)?  I'm happy to read source code if that's the way to learn to do anything, but it's not so easy to understand the syntax for operators like ~> (I haven't learned to read the implicit conversion code yet).  Please teach me how to learn. :)

Comment: Well, I know 2 possible views: how I did it and how I see it could/"should" be done.

Comment: I learned scala, lift and web programming -- all at the same time. The main sequence was -- think how it can be done at all in this "web", then think how it can be done in a framework, then surprisingly find out that Lift did it as I expected. I never read books, I had about 10 bookmarks which I used. About `#>`, `SiteMap`, `forms`, `JSON`, `REST` and such. After a couple of months I understood that reading source helps very much (and reading lift ones is pleasant). I now also read some blogs and watch the mailing list.

Comment: So, what can one learn from this -- it that's it possible to learn the three things simultaneously, that bookmarks and thinking did help with web/scala/lift.

Comment: About recommending -- it's harder. I never was a team lead, only a math teacher long ago.:) I don't know how it works on different people (in programming). So, I can only give a status on different sources about lift. * wiki is good for basic ideas, but sometimes not up to date. It can be edited only by "lift contributors", which I don't like very much. * the mailing list is weakly indexed by search engines, but it's very helpful (and obviously up to date:)

Comment: * the IRC channel is helpful but it's almost not indexed at all. * I don't know about books, only heard they might be good but not up to date. * lift's source is nice to work with. I even use "search usages" and such stuff on it's variables.

Comment: * stackoverflow isn't very popular, but sometimes works. Feel free to ask.:)

And note that the official source is the mailing list.)